# How to Hint for a class definition of a certain type in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

In order to make a reusable Get class, how would I Hint a variable that contains a class definition of a certain protocol instead of an instance? I would like to acchive the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import BaseModel
from somewhere import get  # a function that returns a list of dictionaries

class ObjectOne(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str

class ObjectTwo(BaseModel):
    c: str
    d: int

@dataclass
class Get:
    retrieve_type: Callable  # what do I have to set here to accept 'ObjectOne' or 'ObjectTwo'?
    url: str

    def get(self, ids: List[int]) -> List[BaseModel]:
        response = get(url, ids)
        return [self.retrieve_type(**r) for r in response]
      
# how to use
data_one = Get(retrieve_type=ObjectOne, url="https://myserver/one")
data_two = Get(retrieve_type=ObjectTwo, url="https://myserver/two")

data = data_one.get([1,2,3,4])
```

I understand that Callable works, but is this best practice?

Comment: `Type[ObjectOne | ObjectTwo]`?

Comment: That is not really flexible. I would like to have a plentora of recieve_types, growing as the rest endpoints grow. I don't want them to be defined at two places.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I approached this the wrong way. I should have thought of protocols:

```
from typing import Protocol, Dict Any
from dataclasses import dataclass
from pydantic import BaseModel
from somewhere import get  # a function that returns a list of dictionaries

class RecieveObject(Protocol):
    def dict() -> Dict[str, Any]:
        """returns object as dict, like pydantic"""
    def json() -> str:
        """returns json like pydantic"""
    

class ObjectOne(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: str

class ObjectTwo(BaseModel):
    c: str
    d: int

@dataclass
class Get:
    retrieve_type: RecieveObject  
    url: str

    def get(self, ids: List[int]) -> List[BaseModel]:
        response = get(url, ids)
        return [self.retrieve_type(**r) for r in response]
      
# how to use
data_one = Get(retrieve_type=ObjectOne, url="https://myserver/one")
data_two = Get(retrieve_type=ObjectTwo, url="https://myserver/two")

data = data_one.get([1,2,3,4])
```